# Azure Application insights - records in "dependencies" table causing confusion

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-application-insights

While Performing load testing for a specific business scenario, Azure Application insights shows below records like "create database", "create collection". But in actual code path of execution such functionalities like "create database", "create collection" doesn't exists it more about reading the existing cosmos db document from existing cosmos db collection.

Any idea when & how such records/row will exists in "dependencies" table of Azure Application insights?

Moreover same cosmos db collection called "dbs/YFVzwR==/colls" getting recreated again and again

[image]

Comment: Are you using change feeds?

Comment: No, not in the concerned DB.

Comment: If possible, it would be extremely helpfulif you could include a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what is happening. In particular, I'm curious about the App Insights version/config, Cosmos SDK version, and a minimal version of the related code so it would be possible to reproduce the scenario.